# linQ group by/select - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to create a linQ query which will yield the same outcome as this SQL:

```
SELECT Priority.PriorityKey, Count(Priority.PriorityKey) AS NewPresentingUnits
FROM Priority INNER JOIN SupportPeriod ON Priority.PriorityCode = SupportPeriod.PriorityCode
WHERE (((SupportPeriod.NewClient)=True) AND ((SupportPeriod.DateAssistanceRequested) Between #1/1/2013# And #2/1/2013#) AND ((SupportPeriod.DateFinished) Between #1/1/9999# And #12/31/9999#))
GROUP BY Priority.PriorityKey;
```

I get the following result when i run the SQL query:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvRlBtT1lZWURERVU/edit?usp=sharing

This is the linQ statement:

```
    SupportPeriodTableAdapter spTa = new SupportPeriodTableAdapter();
    SupportPeriodDataTable dataTables = spTa.GetData();
        var test = (from sp in dataTables
                  where (sp.NewClient == true) &&
                      (sp.DateAssistanceRequested >= new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) &&
                      sp.DateAssistanceRequested <= new DateTime(2013, 2, 1)) &&
                      (sp.DateFinished > new DateTime(2013, 2, 1))
                  group sp by sp.PriorityRow.PriorityKey into groupz
                  select new { Key = groupz.Key, sount = groupz.Count() });
```

When i try to debug `var test` i get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" in the results view.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvdGp0bjJCNkE3TTg/edit?usp=sharing

I'm new to using 'group by' and 'select new' features of linQ, thus i'm having a hard time figuring this out....

Comment: `sp.PriorityRow` may be the culprit

Comment: @NSGaga All the FK's in the SupportPeriod table has a valid PK in the Priority table... do you mean i should use multiple queries and not use sp.PriorityRow?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are something going wrong with your data load.

**I will check if all rows in dataTables have PriorityRow**

if there are some rows does not have PriorityRow on it, the group by with fail.
in this case, you can change your linq to:

```
 var test = (from sp in dataTables
             where (sp.NewClient == true) &&
                   (sp.DateAssistanceRequested >= new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) &&
                    sp.DateAssistanceRequested <= new DateTime(2013, 2, 1)) &&
                   (sp.DateFinished > new DateTime(2013, 2, 1))
             group sp by sp.PriorityRow != null 
                               ? sp.PriorityRow.PriorityKey 
                               : "not key"
                      into groupz
             select new { Key = groupz.Key, sount = groupz.Count() });
```

use:
**group sp by sp.PriorityRow != null ? sp.PriorityRow.PriorityKey : "not key" into groupz**